# Backup AWS Workspace file system

Tags: amazon-web-services, backup, remote-desktop, system-administration

I have an workspace in **AWS workspace** with a lot of configuration files, installed software and files with templates, shell scripts and code, so it's fully configured.

My problem is that when I try to create an image, I lost everything but the installed software. So anybody knows how can I create a backup of my AWS workspace to avoid to have to configure the desktop in terrible case where my images and my workspaces was accidentally removed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the official docs,

> A custom image contains only the OS, software, and settings for the WorkSpace. A custom bundle is a combination of both that custom image and the hardware from which a WorkSpace can be launched.

Seems like the image does not carry forward the personal settings like set wallpaper or any browser settings. I experienced this myself.

However, if you are worried about losing whatever configurations you have done if workspace becomes unhealthy, then you can use Rebuild or Restore option.
By default aws takes auto snapshots of root & user volumes of your workspace every 12 hrs.
You can read more bout this [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/latest/adminguide/restore-workspace.html)

> in terrible case where my images and my workspaces was accidentally removed

If your workspace is deleted/ terminated, no data can be retrieved.